# "\n" in php string variable when stored in javascript variable causes line break

Tags: javascript, php

For example my php string variable contain

```
$code="#include<iostream>   using namespace std;

void main() { 

cout<<"Hello world \n"; 

}"
```

And then in javascript, when I do

```
var text=<?php echo json_encode($code); ?> 

console.log(text);
```

Then It gives output

```
"#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void main(){

cout<<"Hello world

";

}"
```

Taking the terminating inverted quotes in the next line.
What should I do.

Comment: The code you have should not work at all since it contains syntax errors (http://codepad.org/FZ9It1wS). You probably want [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc). But yes, using `\n` in a double quoted string will produce a line break, because that's the escape sequence for line breaks. Check out the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double).

Comment: 'What should I do?' strip! whether thats a chevy chase or code strip...either way you'll feel better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with backslash character

```
text=text.replace(/\\n/g,"\\n");
```

Answer (score 2):

Lets go backwards from the desired output to generating the output. You want `console.log` show a value containing `\n`:

```
"foo\nbar"
```

That means the string literal in the JavaScript code must look like

```
var text = '"foo\\nfoo"';
```

`json_encode` already takes care of quotes stuff for us, so all we need to do is produce a PHP string that literally contains `\\n`.

There a couple of ways depending on which way you generate the string:

```
// single quotes
$code = 'foo\\\nbar';

// double quotes
$code = "foo\\\\nbar";

// heredoc (same as double quotes)
$code = <<<CODE
foo\\\\nbar
CODE;
```

Alternatively you could use [`addcslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addcslashes.php) to escape any existing `\` in the string:

```
$code = addslashes('foo\nbar', '\\');
$code = addslashes("foo\\nbar", "\\");
```

Answer (score 1):

Either you escape the backslash when you assign the string to your 'code' variable, like this:

`cout<<"Hello world \\n";`

...or you replace the new line characters before printing the string:

`console.log(text.replace(/\n/,"\\n"));`

Answer (score 1):

Since the wrapped code seems to be C++, you can replace the `\n` by the C++ constant `endl`.

The result would be

```
$code="#include<iostream>   using namespace std;

void main() { 

cout<<\"Hello world \"<<endl; 

}"
```